# What is the true range of possible values of a field type 'DATE'?

Tags: mysql

DATE field type has limitations '1000-01-01' -'9999-12-31'.

BUT Why inserted '987-10-10' not '1000-01-01' ?

```
  mysql> INSERT INTO DATE12(datas) VALUES('987-10-10');
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

    mysql> SELECT * FROM DATE12;
    +------+------------+
    | id   | datas      |
    +------+------------+
    | NULL | 1987-11-04 |
    | NULL | 0987-10-10 |
    +------+------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

incorrect data format

```
 mysql> INSERT INTO DATE12(datas) VALUES('10001-13-12');
    Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

    mysql> SELECT * FROM DATE12;
    +------+------------+
    | id   | datas      |
    +------+------------+
    | NULL | 1987-11-04 |
    | NULL | 0987-10-10 |
    | NULL | 0000-00-00 |
```

But for time type all good

```
mysql> INSERT INTO time1(t) VALUE('-1112:45:12');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM time1;
+------+------------+
| id   | t          |
+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL       |
| NULL | -12:45:12  |
| NULL | -838:59:59 |
+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO time1(t) VALUE('11112:45:12');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM time1;
+------+------------+
| id   | t          |
+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL       |
| NULL | -12:45:12  |
| NULL | -838:59:59 |
| NULL | 838:59:59  |
+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *...Why insered '987-10-10' not '1000-01-01' ?*

As per documentation on [*The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

> For the `DATE` and `DATETIME` range descriptions, “supported” means that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee.

Meaning, the dates prior to `'1000-01-01'` may also be accepted, but not guaranteed.
And hence, in your case the date entry `'987-10-10'` is accepted with no errors.

And you claim that `'1000-01-01'` is not inserted. But you actually tried `'10001-13-12'`.
And even if you try with `'1000-13-12'`, it will fail, because, value `'13'` for `'month'` part is meaning less.

As per documentation on [***Date and Time Literals***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

> As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD`' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.

Though not seen in the documentation, the above statement is also valid for format like `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and others. And the same is shown in the following example:

```
mysql> insert into vdt(dt) values( '1001-13-32' );
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '1001-13-32' for column 'dt' at row 1

mysql> select date_format( '2013-13-32', '%Y-%m-%d' ); show warnings;
+-----------------------------------------+
| date_format( '2013-13-32', '%Y-%m-%d' ) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '2013-13-32' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select str_to_date( '20131232', '%Y%m%d' ); show warnings;
+-------------------------------------+
| str_to_date( '20131232', '%Y%m%d' ) |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                       |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '20131232' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```